# How to write a ` symbol inside a code block

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, code-block

How can I write this symbol: **`** inside a code block in just one line?

As the code blocks are defined by: **```**, I am not able to write one of these inside the code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the term 'code block' to refer to a ... block ... of code, as opposed to 'in-line code'. For that, see the duplicate question. For code blocks, the following Markdown

````
```
`
```
````

produces

```
`
```

Alternatively, you can use the old style code blocks (indentation by four spaces). The following Markdown would work as well:

```
    `
```

Comment: Okay, I've edited the question because I was referring to write everything in the same line, but this solution works!

Comment: @Jeni You can also use a backslash to escape a single backtick in a inline code sample. Eg, inline `code \` sample`, which I wrote using:  `inline \`code \\` sample\``